# Using Fancybox 3 image galleries with thumbnails

Tags: jquery

fancybox3 thumbnail images sliding, if I clicking that thumbnail images which image clicking that image there will be show.. that big images is always showing the first image.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide an online example? it seems to be working fine to me, you can check this example: https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/oBedNj

also if you need to set manually the thumbnail you can add the following to any link to set thumbnail image.

```
data-thumb="link/to/thumb.jpg"
```